# D3 LinearScale NaN

Tags: javascript, d3.js

The code below is my current code. I want to map data out of a GeoJSON to a number between 2 and 50. The only thing it returns is NaN...

```js
shapes.transition()
  .duration(500)
  .attr("width", 12)
  .attr("height", function(d) {
    if (optionArray[i] === "location") {
      return 12;
    }

    if (optionArray[i] === "Average_Age") {
      var x = d3.scaleLinear()
        .range([2, 50])
        .domain(d.properties.Average_Age);

      return x(d.properties.Average_Age);
    }
  });
```

Comment: If `d.properties.Average_Age` is null it's going to cause problems.

Comment: d.properties.Average_Age all have a value, checked that already

Comment: The domain of the scale has to be an array containing the values that map to 2 and 50, the domain is scaled to the range - how can you scale a one value domain to a two value range?.

Comment: @AndrewReid d.properties.Average_Age is 33 values

Comment: In that case, you are passing an array to the scale, but the scale expects a single numerical value to scale.

Answer (score 1):

In the shared portion of code, `x` scale is redefined for each record in the input dataset. This is not necessary and adds overhead.

The `x` scale should be declared only once, outside of the `.attr("height, [...]"` function call.

Then, the parameter of `scaleLinear.domain` functionshould be an array containing the min and max values found in the input dataset (c.f. [example](https://github.com/d3/d3-scale#continuous-scales) in the library's documentation. The utility function `d3.extent` can be used to return such an array (read:  [Setting Scales Domains and Ranges in d3.js](http://www.d3noob.org/2012/12/setting-scales-domains-and-ranges-in.html) ).

Assuming that your dataset is called `data`, the code should be:

```
var x = d3.scaleLinear()
  .range([2, 50])
  .domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.properties.Average_Age; }));

shapes.transition()
  .duration(500)
  .attr("width", 12)
  .attr("height", function(d) {
    if (optionArray[i] === "location") {
      return 12;
    }

    if (optionArray[i] === "Average_Age") {

      return x(d.properties.Average_Age);
    }
  });
```